# Using Beautiful Soup to log in web page and download multiple zip files

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, download, unzip

I am first time users to web **scraping** and Beautiful soup.

I have two queries first to pass login information to the files I want download and secondly to download multiple zip file. I am pasting my code below without the curl/log in information.

Firstly, I have a web page which requires log in to download file. I am able to log in with Beautiful soup but thereafter I unable to go further as I not able to pass the login information in python to the particular file I want to download. So basically how can I let python know to use the login credential to the file= baseurl+href_link file.

And secondly my link file is a zip file without having .zip at the end. For example my   `baseurl= 'https://consumerpyramidsdx.cmie.com'` and href_link file `/kommon/bin/sr.php? kall=wsubsdl&fn=consumption_pyramids_20140131_MS_rev&fmt=csv&rrurl=consumptionpyramidsdx` So how can I use it download all the zip files and unzip it? Most of the forum query on this uses '.zip' explicitly as their href has .zip but in my case it doesn't.

Sample zip file which get downloaded after click href_link is Sample zip file name which get downloaded is "consumption_pyramids_20140131_MS_rev_csv"

My code are following:

```
response = requests.post('https://consumerpyramidsdx.cmie.com/kommon/bin/sr.php', headers=headers, params=params, cookies=cookies, data=data)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "lxml")
baseurl= 'https://consumerpyramidsdx.cmie.com'
print(soup) 

for x in soup.find_all("a"):
    if x.text =='CSV':
        file_link = x.get('href') #contains the href_link file I want to download 
        print(file_link)
        # After this I want to download all the baseurl+file_link files
```

Answer (score 0):

my suggestions:

The method one

```py
response = requests.get(url=url,headers=headers)
content = response.content
with open("xxxx.zip", "wb") as f:
    f.write(content)
```

this url is your will be downloaded website url. this XXXX is your file name, zip file.

the method two

```py
import wget 
url = ""
wget.download(url, path)
```

the path is your zip fill will be saved path on your Mac/Linux/windows.

The last but not the least, while you are decompressing files, you can use zipfile, for example:

```py
import zipfile

zip_file = zipfile.ZipFile(path)
zip_list = zip_file.namelist() # get all files after decompressing files.

# Cycle unzip files to the specified directory。
for f in zip_list:
    zip_file.extract(f, floder_abs)

zip_file.close()
```

Thanks for your reading, it's my honor. If these suggestions have any question, please tell me.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for the help but unfortunately its not working. In the first code I get a xxx.zip file which when I open it says unsupported format. In the second I get all the file in the format '.php'.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in one go (assuming you checked that your current code works and is correct):

```
for x in soup.find_all("a"):
    if x.text =='CSV':
        file_link = x.get('href')
        response = requests.get(url=urllib.parse.urljoin(baseurl, file_link), headers=headers)
        content = response.content
        with zipfile.ZipFile(io.BytesIO(content)) as zf:
            zf.extractall('target/directory')
```

Comment: Implementing your code I get error BadZipFile: File is not a zip file

Comment: That seems to suggest that the response you're getting is not actually a zip file... I don't have access to the site you're referring to, so I can't test to tell you what's wrong

Comment: This is the website https://consumerpyramidsdx.cmie.com/kommon/bin/sr.php?kall=wdpi&rrurl=consumptionpyramidsdx                                                                and sample file link is " /kommon/bin/sr.php? kall=wsubsdl&fn=consumption_pyramids_20140131_MS_rev&fmt=csv&rrurl=consumptionpyramidsdx"     Clicking on the link zip files get downloaded

Comment: Sample zip file name which get downloaded is   "consumption_pyramids_20140131_MS_rev_csv"

Comment: I think the problem is getting file name from the href link for example from the above the href is "/kommon/bin/sr.php? kall=wsubsdl&fn=consumption_pyramids_20140131_MS_rev&fmt=csv&rrurl=consumptionpyramidsdx"  and then from this we have to extract file name "consumption_pyramids_20140131_MS_rev" + "_csv"

Answer (score 0):

The above answers are letting me to solve my second problem which was downloading the zip files and unzipping it. But this only works if I am able solve my first problem which was letting python to know log the information for each href linked file. The command session() let me solve the first problem. So here is the code:

```
s = requests.Session() 
    
url= 'https://consumerpyramidsdx.cmie.com/kommon/bin/sr.php?kall=wdpi&rrurl=consumptionpyramidsdx'
response = s.post(url, data=data)  
print (response.status_code) 
req = s.get(url)
print(req.status_code) 
soup = BeautifulSoup(req.content, "lxml") print(soup)


baseurl= 'https://consumerpyramidsdx.cmie.com'

for x in soup.find_all("a"):
    if x.text =='CSV':
        file_link = x.get('href')
        print(file_link[37:65]+"Downloading" )
        response = s.get(url=urllib.parse.urljoin(baseurl, file_link),headers=headers)
        content = response.content
        with zipfile.ZipFile(io.BytesIO(content)) as zf:
            zf.extractall('file/directory')
```