# Downloading a file from webpage using python, getting a html file instead of the actual zip file

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, gzip

I am trying to download a file from a webpage which requires log in. I am able to log in  through python and Beautiful Soup. But when I try to download a file through python from that page I get an html file instead of getting intended zip file. On the webpage when the file link is clicked a new window is opened and ask to download the file. The download file is in zip format. So please help me to download the file through the python.

```
response = requests.post('https://consumerpyramidsdx.cmie.com/kommon/bin/sr.php', headers=headers, params=params, cookies=cookies, data=data) 
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "lxml")
baseurl= 'https://consumerpyramidsdx.cmie.com'
print(soup)

file_url = 'https://consumerpyramidsdx.cmie.com/kommon/bin/sr.php?kall=wsubsdl&fn=consumption_pyramids_20210630_MS&fmt=csv&rrurl=consumptionpyramidsdx'

with open('consumption_pyramids_20210630_MS_csv.zip', 'wb') as file:
     rs = requests.get(file_url)
     file.write(rs.content)
```

Comment: That entirely depends on the target site, how the downloads are started there. You basically need to find the link to the actual file, and not just save the website containing the link.

Comment: Hi, file_url is the link of the actual file; Baseurl+ href_file= file_url

Comment: Obivously not, no. Otherwise you would actually download a proper file instead of the html. That is probably a regular page with either a download button and / or a timer that starts the download after a short wait time. But evidently it is not the link to the actual file. *Maybe* you need to fake some headers, depending on what the site does, e.g. the `Origin` header. You simply need to spend some time playing around with it, this is basically reverse engineering the download process, takes time. Maybe you need to send some cookies along, maybe this, maybe that...

Comment: By trying stuff out for a couple of days, try, try, try, ... Open the network tab, capture the actual download call, copy the request e.g. as curl, try to execute it on the terminal, remove stuff from the request to figure out what is actually required for the download, and then try to replicate that request in python...

Comment: So my actual problem is this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70120185/using-beautiful-soup-to-log-in-web-page-and-download-multiple-zip-files/70120324?noredirect=1#comment123953769_70120324) So I am guessing my original problem is not working because of the subproblem posted here. Tell me If I am on right track. I want to fix this first and move to the original problem next, that would be correct?

Comment: The problem is that you do not have a working link to a file. And you need to figure out the direct link to the file, this takes time, experience and skill, check the network tab, check curl, check .... I stop responding now because this is going nowhere

Answer (score 0):

The problem it was giving me html file because the log in information of the base-url were not passed on the href file. It works with the command session.

Follow the link to see how to solve the problem:
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70120185/using-beautiful-soup-to-log-in-web-page-and-download-multiple-zip-files)